# how to pass lambda expression with arguments as parameters in Java 8?

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-interface

Here is what I tried. and it does not even compile.

```
public class LambdaExample {

    public static Integer handleOperation(Integer x, Integer y,  Function converter){
                return converter.apply(x,y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         handleOperation(10,10, Operation::add);
    }

}

class Operation {

    public int add(Integer x, Integer y){
        return x+y;
    }

}
```

Couple of things I am trying to acheive/learn here is:

1) how to pass `lambda expression` as method parameter ( in `main` method above)

2) how to pass parameters to the function (in  `handleOpertion` method, there is `compilation` error that apply takes only one parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `handleOperation` method takes an object that implements `Function`, `Operation::add` (a method reference) doesn't qualify. Also, for two arguments, you'll need to use `BiFunction` instead.

Here's an example that should work:

```
public class LambdaExample {

    public static Integer handleOperation(Integer x, Integer y,  BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> converter){
                return converter.apply(x,y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         handleOperation( 10,10, new Operation() ); // should return 20
    }

}

class Operation implements BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

    public Integer apply(Integer x, Integer y){
        return x+y;
    }

}
```

Updated:

```
public class LambdaExample {

    public static Integer handleOperation(Integer x, Integer y,  BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> converter){
                return converter.apply(x,y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         handleOperation( 10,10, Operation::add ); // should return 20
    }

}

class Operation {

    public static int add(Integer x, Integer y){
        return x+y;
    }

}
```

Comment: NO this is not what I wanted.. I want to pass "add" function in lambda. I dont want to pass `new Operation()` there..

Answer (score 5):

A `Function` takes an input x and yield a result y. Thus you are not looking for a `Function` (not mentioning that you used a raw type) when doing `return converter.apply(x,y);`, but for a `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>` or more simpler, a `BinaryOperator<Integer>` since every type parameter is identical.

> 1) how to pass lambda expression as method parameter ( in main method
>   above)

By providing a lambda expression that respect the contract of the `BinaryOperator<Integer>` interface, i.e a method that takes two `Integer` as parameter and return an `Integer`.

```
handleOperation(10,10, (a, b) -> a + b)
```

> 2) how to pass parameters to the function (in  handleOpertion method,
>   there is compilation error that apply takes only one parameter)

Because a function is of the form `f => u` thus the apply method takes a single argument and yield a single result, like a mathematical function such as `f(x) = 2 * x` (refer to the first part of the answer).

> Here is what I tried. and it does not even compile.

To make your code compile, you can either make the method static or create a new instance before using the method reference. Then it will refer to the `add` method of the new instance when `handleOperation` will call the apply method of the function.

```
handleOperation(10,10, new Operation()::add);
```

Note that this method already exists in the JDK, it's `Integer::sum`. It takes two primitive int values instead of `Integer` references but it's close enough so that the auto-boxing mechanism will make this method valid to appear as a `BinaryOperator<Integer>` in the method context.

Comment: Thanks. I crafted this example based on our production code. There I see `handleRequest( getToken(), (token) -> service.makeRequest(token, ID))`. In the `handleRequest(String token, Function<A,B> function) { return function.apply(token)}`. I was thinking if I can convert this to `service::makeRequest`. But I guess it is not possible..

Comment: @brainstorm No, I don't think, because of the `ID` parameter. But the lambda is fine, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Your Function parameter is raw (untyped) and should be a BiFunction.

Try this:

```
public static Integer handleOperation(Integer x, Integer y,  BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> converter){
    return converter.apply(x,y);
}
```

A BiFunction with all 3 types the same can replaced with a (single-typed) BinaryOperator:

```
public static Integer handleOperation(Integer x, Integer y,  BinaryOperator<Integer> converter){
    return converter.apply(x,y);
}
```

To call it, you can do this:

```
int sum = handleOperation(1, 2, (x, y) -> x + y); // 3
```

Actually, you have implemented a *reduction*. This call could equally be written as:

```
int sum = Stream.of(1, 2).reduce((x, y) -> x + y);
```